# Pass variable to partial(rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a partial _album.html.erb and it has a variable "album"
I have a collection @albums . For each in the collection I want to render the partial. But I  don't use the option "collection:" because I want to put each one in different position.  Here is my code:

```
<% @albums.each do | f | %>
     ..........
    <td>
           <%= render partial: "album", locals: {"album" f} %>
      .........
<% end %>
```

This code returns a SyntaxError. I don't know why this happens.

Comment: Actually it will be very helpful if you posted logs with Error

Answer (score 5):

You haven't any divider between `"album"` and  `f`, so try `locals: {album: f}` or `:album => f`

Comment: I have a space there . It's my phone's problem. But Thanks

Comment: You can't use space, it's a hash. Use `=>` or `:` ad I suggest.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstand you. I have ":" Between album and f . And have a space between : and f.

Comment: Ok, got it. Perhaps then, in partial are you using `@album`? Cause this location variable will be just `album`. Use this name instead, and return it in other calls as local.

Comment: I use it as album.title. So it just local variable not instance variable .

Comment: Good. Have you tried `album` without double quotes? `locals: {album: f}`. This caused error for me.

Comment: I have solved this problem . I had syntax problem in the partial . But I wonder why the log doesn't  trace in the partial . Just gives error  to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

**Locals**

Further to `zishe`'s correct answer, you'll need to look up on how to set the syntax for `partial` [`local variables`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables):

```
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {zone: @zone} %>
```

Rails basically sends a [`hash`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm) of `key: value` pairs, which means the syntax *has* to be like this:

```
locals: {key: value, "key" => value}
```

You have to remember Rails is basically just a collection of files & classes, which means anything you do has to conform to the ways in which Ruby allows you to assign & pass data, a `hash` being one of the main ways

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I tried with `locals: {..}` but it didn't work.

You can try this that worked for me:

```
 <%= render partial: "form", zone: @zone %>
```